# Difference between "as" and "because"?

Tags: word-choice, difference, conjunctions, synonyms, ambiguity

What is the difference between *as* and *because*? Which one of these sentences is correct?

> He stayed home from work *as* he was sick?
>
> He stayed home form work *because* he was sick?

Which is correct?
Are they both correct?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*As* is used to mean *because*, but it is also used when two events happen at the same time.

In "I must stop now as I have to go out." it means *because*, but in "She watched him as the train passed close to his house." it doesn't mean *because*.

As for the sentences you used as examples, both are correct.

Comment: *As* can also mean *like, in the same way* - for example, *"She watched him as a cat watches a mouse"*. Another difference in the "because" sense is that you don't normally use it to start a sentence. So you can't just perform the substitution in something like *"Why did you do that?" "Because I felt like it"*.

Comment: @Fu: Is there a somewhere with a written rule (I mean "suggestion", of course) that says _Thou shalt not use **because** to start a sentence_? I ask only because I read a comment somewhere else that said _because_ was "too informal for formal written expository prose". I eschew ambiguity in technical writing & will always begin a sentence with _because_ rather than the villainous "As What Ate Because to Steal Its Soul", just as I will slay its equally villainous fraternal twin "Due To" & replace it with _because of_. _Clarity_ is my hero.

Answer (score 3):

In some contexts, any of *as*, *since*, and *because* can be used.  kiamlaluno's example, “I must stop now as I have to go out” is one such context.

However, I believe most native speakers would shun “He stayed home from work as he was sick”, instead preferring either  “He stayed home from work since he was sick” or “He stayed home from work because he was sick”.

Comment: Are you sure people prefer _since_? To me, the sentence can be ambiguous with _since_, as it can also be an indication of time, and I'd avoid it for that reason.

Comment: @MrLister, while technically the sentence with *since* is ambiguous, as a practical matter it will be understood as explaining *why* he stayed home from work, rather than *when*.  “He stayed home from work while he was sick” would be preferred for that.

Answer (score 2):

The major differences between *as* and *because* are three, in ascending order of importance:

> *As* has two letters, and *because* has seven: point to *as*
>   *As* has one syllable, and *because* has two: point to *as*
>   *As* is often ambiguous, but *because* never is: 10 points to *because*

If you care about clarity (I do), then you should never use an ambiguous word when there is a perfectly acceptable **unambiguous** word that can be used instead.

The two sentences in your question are both grammatically correct and both idiomatic native-speaker versions of the same semantic content. The first is more likely in British English than in American English, to which, however, it is no stranger.

You might want to look at this related SE question and answer: [When are "because", "since","for" and "as" interchangeable?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6993/when-are-because-since-for-and-as-interchangeable) And [this page of advice](http://300daysofbetterwriting.wordpress.com/2010/11/05/because-vs-as/) about using *as* and *because*. And this well-researched *[Grammar Girl](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/because-due-to-since-as.aspx)* page.

Answer (score 0):

I believe both are correct because both are speaking of the reason why the person stayed at home from work.

Comment: Mind expanding a little bit? This reads like a comment. Why both "as" and "because" can be used to explain a reason? Also I would appreciate it if you include more sources than "you".

Answer (score 0):

'He stayed home from work as he was sick' would be correct if we want to focus on the result (He stayed home). but if you want to emphasise or focus more on the reason, then 'because he was sick' would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

The word "as" is used for expressing comparisons: She was as pretty as an angel; the cold wind was as sharp as a knife. When "as" is used any other way, the writer could be making a much better word choice, such as because, since, while, or when. "As" does not mean because or since. If the dictionary claims it does, it is only doing so because of frequent incorrect usage, not because it is right.

An example above uses the sentence: "She watched him as the train passed close to his house." In this sentence, while or when is a better word choice. Also, I would flip the sentence: When the train passed close to his house, she watched him. Or, While the train passed close to his house, she watched him.