# What is 'as' and its meaning in this sentence?

Tags: conjunctions, interpretation

> **As** I live with three dogs, I am very happy to let my dogs run around and safely play with other dogs from the neighborhood.

As what meaning can I interpret the word "as" here?

Comment: Related: [Difference between “as” and “because”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/917/9161)

Comment: The cited text isn't really "valid", so the only "meaning" we should assign to it is *writer (whether native Anglophone or not) doesn't know English very well*.

Comment: I guess the translators of the King James Bible "didn't know English very well". See Ezekiel 18:3 and 20:3, Romans 14:11, etc.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: That text is perfectly fine. The use of "as" to mean "because" is entirely standard English.

Comment: @Kevin: My point is *that interpretation makes no sense*. You might as well say ***Because** I have a husband, I don't mind if he's unfaithful*. Obviously it's not possible to mind about having an unfaithful husband unless you've actually ***got*** a husband in the first place. Equally, you can't be happy to let your dogs roam free unless you've actually got some dogs. But in and of itself, actually ***having*** said husband or dogs can't meaningfully be cited as the ***reason*** for having specific attitudes to them.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: That's very subjective. IMHO it's perfectly sensible if we assume that the speaker's home is rather small and can only barely accommodate three dogs. But regardless, there is no other reasonable interpretation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have used it, *As* comes very close to meaning **since or because** but doesn't quite mean either of those things.  *Since or Because* would be setting up a causal relationship.

If the relationship was causal and you were asked ***Why** you let your dogs run around and play*, you could say ***Because** I have three dogs*.  *As* sets up a similar relationship with a much softer implication of causality.

**As** in your sentence merely establishes a relative situation without implying causality.  The meaning is closer to *I am a dog owner.  I let my dogs run around and play.*  Maybe that's causal.  Maybe it's not.

Answer (score 4):

"As" at the beginning of this sentence appears to mean "Given that".

This is not actually a correct usage of the word. It should either be "Given that" or "Since". "Since" would mean "Because" here, which also doesn't really make sense in context.

Comment: I disagree that this is "not a correct usage." This sort of construction is explicitly endorsed in [*Merriam-Webster*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as) (conjunction, sense 7), which also states that "as" is a *synonym* of "because" or "since."